# Can't delete or rename files in Xcode 4.6 Project Navigator?

Tags: xcode

Something has become buggered with my project.

I can't delete files or rename files from Project Navigator view.

It may have something to do with source control?  If I highlight 5 files in Project Navigator and hit delete and then move to trash the first file gets a source control "D" marking beside it but all of the files still remain.

Restarting mac/xcode has not resolved it.   Any ideas?

Comment: Which source control are you using: subversion, git...?

Comment: Using git.  I haven't had these problems with the project in the past so something seems buggered

Comment: I am using XCode 4.6 and git, and not seeing this behaviour. Is the XCode project file being updated for the deleted files? Are the files gone from the navigator after you commit?

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happens to me for a while now.
Using git.

So far I'm able to work around this by deleting the files one at a time, which moves the file to trash but doesn't remove the reference. And then deleting the references again.

Similar problem with adding files to the project and renaming them.
For adding: first move/copy the required file in the project folder to the desired location, and then add from Xcode deselecting the "Copy items..." checkbox.
For renaming: find file in finder, rename IN FINDER, then change the name accordingly in Xcode (or choose the file again from the right panel).

Hopefully we won't have problems like these after moving to Xcode 5.